# new to Zedboard : how to allocate "clk" pin number on the zedboard?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, zynq

I'm very new to Zedboard. I'm writing a counter in VHDL, and try to implement it on the Zedboard Zynq 7000 XC7Z020-1 CSG484CES EPP.

When I allocate the pin, I want to have a clock. But it seems wrong to allocate "clk" to a user switch. So I looked up the document `ZedBoard_HW_UG_v1_1.pdf`.

In chapter 2.5, it says the following:

> The EPP’s PS subsystem uses a dedicated 33.3333 MHz clock source, IC18, Fox 767-
>   33.333333-12, with series termination. The PS infrastructure can generate up to four PLL-based clocks for the PL system. An on-board 100 MHz oscillator, IC17, Fox 767-100-136, supplies the PL subsystem clock input on bank 13, pin Y9.

But when I allocate *NET "clk" LOC = Y9;*, it seems doesn't work! I can't find where the clk is! There suppose to be a button or something that I can control, right?

The warning is this:

PhysDesignRules:2452 - The IOB q<1> is either not constrained (LOC) to a specific location and/or has an undefined I/O Standard (IOSTANDARD). This condition may seriously affect the device and will be an error in bitstream creation. It should be corrected by properly specifying the pin location and I/O Standard.

every pin has a warning like this. 
And here is my ucf file:

```
NET "clk" CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE = FALSE;
NET "q[6]" LOC = T22;
NET "q[5]" LOC = T21;
NET "q[4]" LOC = U22;
NET "q[3]" LOC = U21;
NET "q[2]" LOC = V22;
NET "q[1]" LOC = W22;
NET "q[0]" LOC = U19;

NET "d[6]" LOC = G22;
NET "d[5]" LOC = H22;
NET "d[4]" LOC = F21;
NET "d[3]" LOC = H19;
NET "d[2]" LOC = H18;
NET "d[1]" LOC = H17;
NET "d[0]" LOC = M15;
NET "clk" LOC = Y9;
NET "clr" LOC = T18;
NET "alm" LOC = U14;
```

Where can I find a document explain what I need to do?
And if Y9 is the correct choice for clock, how can I know the upper edge has come? since there's no botton that I can operate?
A lot of thanks!!!

Comment: Using Y9 is correct. Does ISE or Vivado acknoledge your containt?

Comment: @Paebbels Yes, it doesn't report error about Y9, but every signal(input and output) has a warning like this :[PhysDesignRules 2452] The IOB clr is either not constrained (LOC) to a specific location and/or has an undefined I/O Standard (IOSTANDARD). This condition may seriously affect the device and will be an error in bitstream creation. It should be corrected by properly specifying the pin location and I/O Standard.So I don't know how to do with it..

Comment: Have you set a IOSTANDARD additionally to the LOC? Does ISE read your ucf file (there are cases when ISE ignores a ucf file). You can look this up if translate is called with your ucf file as a command line parameter.

Comment: @Paebbels sorry I don't know about IOSTANDARD...here is my ucf file:NET "clk" CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE = FALSE;
NET "q[6]" LOC = T22;
NET "q[5]" LOC = T21;
NET "q[4]" LOC = U22;
NET "q[3]" LOC = U21;
NET "q[2]" LOC = V22;
NET "q[1]" LOC = W22;
NET "q[0]" LOC = U19;

NET "d[6]" LOC = G22;
NET "d[5]" LOC = H22;
NET "d[4]" LOC = F21;
NET "d[3]" LOC = H19;
NET "d[2]" LOC = H18;
NET "d[1]" LOC = H17;
NET "d[0]" LOC = M15;
NET "clk" LOC = Y9;
NET "clr" LOC = T18;
NET "alm" LOC = U14;

Comment: Please edit your question and add the UCF content there.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add IOSTANDARDs to your ucf file. The complete list of pins and the constraints is listed in the [master ucf file](http://zedboard.org/sites/default/files/zedboard_master_UCF_RevC_v2.zip)

For example pin Y9 needs LVCMOS33.

Comment: Wow...I saw your file, is that the correct way to write a ucf file? Where can I find a book or mannal that explain this in detail? And if Y9 is the correct choice for clock, how can I know the upper edge has come? since there's no botton that I can operate?  Sorry I'm very new to zedboard and very confused...

Comment: This is the complete ucf. You need to copy the lines for your pins. Since 7-series FPGAs ISE requires IOSTANDARDs for every pin. Xilinx offers a "Constraints User Guide" that explains all possible constraints not only for ucf files and pins.